# Postback in IE10 works, not in lower versions

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web application build in ASPX and C# which is used for adding some simple values, this includes a textbox and a few checkboxes.
To start with, I have a panel. From the code behind I build up a table to make it a little bit more pretty and in this table I put the textbox and all the checkboxes.

When the user then fills in the values and presses submit I rebuild the table so I can then read the values in the following way:

```
List<Control> ctrlList = new List<Control>();

Table tbl = (Table)pnlPopup.FindControl("TblPopup");

foreach (TableRow tr in tbl.Rows)
{
    foreach (TableCell td in tr.Cells)
    {
        foreach (Control ctrl in td.Controls)
        {
            ctrlList.Add(ctrl);
        }
     }
}
```

For some reason when I run all the code in `IE10`, it all works fine. This is also the case in `Chrome`. However in `IE9` and lower it doesnt work, I always get an empty table in return.

`Addition:`

Doing some further investigation, i noticed that a `hiddenfield` which i am using to check if it is a new item or an item being edited, loses its value in `IE9` and lower.

Comment: Can you post the HTML code for the hidden field?. Also the Onload event of the page you are running.

Comment: After a bit of testing, i found out that the `HiddenField` was the problem. Replaced it with a `Label` and that did the trick. Still dont know why it fails on a `HiddenField` though